# How to find out why VirtualBox won't read my .vmdk files?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, virtual-machine

Some time ago I made virtual drives from a flash drive using [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-a-usb-flash-drive-in-virtualbox/) tutorial. The images (all 3 of them of a same drive) worked "fine", that is to say they did mount, and I was busy solving the problems in [this](https://superuser.com/q/356720/36601) question.

Then suddenly VirtualBox stopped detecting them! Basically I have a triangle with exclamation mark in it next to the virtual drive and the error I get on mouseover is VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

The interesting thing is that all images are copies of one and that one mounted fine. One of the copies mounted fine too and I didn't touch the third at all. Furthermore I didn't change any VirtualBox settings and I didn't edit the files themselves in any way.

So how do I find out what's going on?

Comment: Is the file not found literal?  Are the disk images in the location that vbox is expecting?

Comment: @Paul Yes, they are. I quoted the error directly. When I open the dialog box to select the images, I can see them and select them and when I do, I get `
Резултат Код:
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Компонент:
Medium
Интерфејс:
IMedium {53f9cc0c-e0fd-40a5-a404-a7a5272082cd}
Позвано:
IVirtualBox {c28be65f-1a8f-43b4-81f1-eb60cb516e66}
` and I can't select it. The files seem to be OK. Also moving the images to another directory does not help and changing names does not help. When I try to start the VM, I get `No error info` error.

Comment: What operating system is this? Could it be a permissions issue?

Comment: @Paul Host is windows 7 64bit, but I doubt that it's permissions issue. I didn't change the permissions. I simply shut down the computer and after I started it again, the problem appeared. The permissions are same as they were. Also running as administrator doesn't help. By the way, I have few more VMs that run fine in the same directory as the ones which don't.